# Calculate the Indefinite integral

Tags: integration, special-functions

I've been stuck with calculating the intgral of the following problem. Can you help me?‎

$$‎\int e^{x^2} \mathrm{d}x‎$$

I ‎know ‎that‎, by Using the definition of gamma and beta functions, we have ‎$‎\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x = ‎\sqrt{\pi}‎‎$.

Thanks‎ in advance.

Comment: Did you find anything relevant in Google? https://socratic.org/answers/141272

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function

Comment: There is no elementary function that is an antiderivative of either $e^{\pm z^2}$. The ["error function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Derivative_and_integral) is a new function defined to be essentially one of these antiderivatives.

Comment: see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154968/is-there-really-no-way-to-integrate-e-x2) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634975/how-can-one-prove-the-impossibility-of-writing-int-ex2-mathrmdx) and linked questions therein, there's everything one needs to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there really no way to integrate $e^{-x^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154968/is-there-really-no-way-to-integrate-e-x2)

Comment: GEdgar. Thanks. But, my question was mentioned abov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the best things we can do about this one is to expand the function into the Taylor series and formally integrate term by term:
$$\int e^{x^2}dx= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}dx= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)k!}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

AD's point is right, however it can be written down in terms of *non*-elementary functions so, we make new function as its evaluation.

$\operatorname{erf} (x) $ is the [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html), defined as $\operatorname{erf}(z)= \frac {2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^z e^{-t^2} dt$

If $I(x)=\int e^{-x^2}dx$,
$$\operatorname{erf}(x)= \frac {2}{\sqrt{\pi}} (I(x)-I(0)) \\
I(x)=\int e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \operatorname{erf}(x)+I(0) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \operatorname{erf}(x)+ C$$