# How can we know if an integrand's antiderivative can be expressed in terms of elementary functions without evaluating for it?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have seen people deduce at a glance that a given integrand's antiderivative cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. How is this done?

Comment: They might know already that certain forms don't have elementary antiderivatives, or they might recognize the integral as related to a special function.

Comment: They recognize known forms. You might want to look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634975/how-can-one-prove-the-impossibility-of-writing-int-ex2-mathrmd) for a brief discussion related to $\int \exp (x^2)\, dx$, one of the first to be proven to be "unintegrable" in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: thank you for the replies. I looked at the linked question and skimmed through the article on liouville's theorem but I've never studied differential algebra before. Is there a procedure I can do to verify if an elementary function's antiderivative is elementary?

Comment: afaik, Liouville's theorem is the only systematical result in that field. I have however never seen a practitioner using it. What I have seen a lot were the phenomenal skills of experienced people spotting the tricks.